# can solidity contracts be linked to specific world events?

Tags: solidity

Can solidity contracts be linked to specific world events?

For instance could a dapp have been created where people were able to bet on Trump or Clinton winning the last US election? If yes how would the dapp have known who the winner is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a guarantee that everything will be fine - my answer is not, its impossible in `Ethereum`. Because when you created a smart-contract, it trusts only in `Ethereum` blockchain events, like new blocks/transactions. Your `smart-contract` have no idea what happens in our real world.

US election it's event from real life, not form `Ethereum` blockchain. So it means that someone should send a transaction to `Ethereum` blockchain with election results. Someone trustable for all players who make a bets. You can use one of providers, for example, `oraclize.it`. It works well and looks trustable, but it means that provider's address has access to your `smart-contract` and can send transactions with any data to it.

It's common solution for getting ETH/USD rate from exchange. 
There is a simple example to get exchange price with `oraclize.it` `https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-best-practices-precalculating-the-query-price